# No parameterless constructor defined for this object. (Debug never reaches any controller action?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I hate these kind of errors.

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC form.   When I submit the form I get the dreaded "No parameterless constructor defined for this object." error.

I can't seem to hit anything in the debugger to help me find where I have went wrong.

**My controller:**

```
using Brand.Extensions;
using Brand.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Brand.Controllers
{
    public class ContentController : Controller
    {

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Upload()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Upload(UploadedContentModel uploadedContentModel, FormCollection formCollection, IFormFileCollection uploadedFiles)
        {
            ContentExtensions contentExtensions = new ContentExtensions();
            FileExtensions fileExtensions = new FileExtensions();
            FileModel file = new FileModel();
            file = fileExtensions.GetFileModel(uploadedFiles["File"]);
            uploadedContentModel.File = fileExtensions.UploadFile(file).ID;

            FileModel thumbnail = new FileModel();
            thumbnail = fileExtensions.GetFileModel(uploadedFiles["Thumbnail"]);
            uploadedContentModel.Thumbnail = fileExtensions.UploadFile(thumbnail).ID;

            uploadedContentModel.ID = contentExtensions.UploadContent(uploadedContentModel).ID;

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**My model:**

```
public class UploadedContentModel
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public Guid File { get; set; }
    public Guid Thumbnail { get; set; }
    public string ContentType { get; set; } 
    public string Solutions { get; set; }
    public string Industries { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalTags { get; set; }
    public DateTime Publish { get; set; }
    public DateTime Expire { get; set; }
    public string AuthorizedRoles { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure which object is throwing the error but have you tried adding a constructor explicitly?

Comment: What does the constructor for a `UploadedContentModel` look like?

Comment: I actually tracked it down to the FormCollection formCollection, attribute in the Upload method.   If I remove that, it works fine.   But shouldn't that collection exist automagically on a form post?

Comment: Could you post the entire stack trace of the error?

Comment: Can you add default constructor `UploadedContentModel(){}`.

Comment: I believe it is related to: https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/issues/186

Comment: It appears that FormCollection is not supported as a parameter in .net-core MVC yet.